# i am having an error with strings and ints and conversion Java

Tags: java

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0000000000000000000000000-12147483648"

I got this error with this code - (only some of it)
I think this part is the main problem

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            strnumgrid += grid[i][j];
        }
    }



        numgrid = Integer.parseInt(strnumgrid);
        numgrid ++;
```

Comment: This was the whole error:       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0000000000000000000000000-12147483648"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at Main.gridCalc(Main.java:70)
 at Main.main(Main.java:39)

Comment: So, what is your question? What don't you understand in the error message you get.

Comment: My question is do you have any idea why this error message is popping up with that code. I don't have a clue what that error has to do with my code.

Comment: It pops up because you're trying to parse the string "0000000000000000000000000-12147483648" to an integer. And that string doesn't represent a valid integer.

Comment: But if you look at the code, I don't see how it would generate that string at all (though thanks for your answers).

Comment: I see it: you're concatenating all the elements of the grid matrix. Let's say it just has 4 elements `0`, `-1`, `2`and `4`: concatenating them will give the string "0-124". And this is not a valid integer. What are you trying to achieve with the code you posted?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. What I am trying to achieve is solving a latin square but with certain rules in place. If you don't know what that is, it is very similar to sudoku. So in essence,I am solving a sudoku - just not exactly the same - if you would like further explanation just ask.